# name "model" is not defined Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have this error while saving mode:

> NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 Model.save(model, filepath="image_ocr/model.h5")
>
> NameError: name 'model' is not defined

```
//imports:
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import Model
import os
import itertools
import codecs
import re
import datetime
import cairocffi as cairo
import editdistance
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage
import pylab
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import Reshape, Lambda
from keras.layers.merge import add, concatenate
from keras.layers.recurrent import GRU
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from keras.preprocessing import image
import keras.callbacks

//training model

Model.save("model.h5")
```

Error is only in last line, but I use 'model' earlier without any errors.
I can't understand where is error.

Comment: The code and error message don't match, please add a self-contained example that reproduces the problem. Also note that this just looks like a typo in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post the full script of your code, it's hard to tell which line causes the problem. Based on my experience, similar error messages may arise when saving or loading model commands are mistakenly formulated. For example, check the .h5 file is a string enclosed by quotation mark when you formulate the model saving line like

```
model.save("my_model.h5")
```

As for resolution for errors that arise in the model loading part, check if your `custom_object` is clearly defined. Hope this is useful.